# Android - EditText isn't filling up available space in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm having an issue with my `EditText` (with id of body) not filling up the available space in my layout. I've been searching everywhere and experimenting with numerous resources, but I just simply can not seem to get it and have been spending hours on literally just this.. I'm guessing there is an issue with how my entire layout is set up, and probably can't just make a tweak in `EditText`. By the way this layout is being used in a fragment, maybe that changes things? I'm not sure, what do you guys think? Thanks for any and all help! Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/title" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/title" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/body" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="write those saucy lyrics"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:text="@string/confirm"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/btnEmail"
        android:alpha="1"   />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm looking for my design to look like this (taken from my graphical layout editor):

[image]

However on my device it looks like this(snapshot from my device):

[image]

Comment: try this to your `EditText android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: Tried it now...Nope didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in Body edit text

So that it becomes

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"        
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

UPDATE:

Plz try following layout

```
<!-- Put the buttons at the bottom -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_lay_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Confirm" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:text="Emial" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Put the title layout at the top of parent  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Occupy rest of the space of screen -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@id/rel_lay_btn" 
    android:layout_below="@id/lin_lay_title">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Body" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"            
        android:gravity="top" 
        android:layout_weight="1"           
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried it now and it didn't work... :/ do you think there might be something else where in my layout that is preventing it from filling available space?

Comment: are you using this layout within another layout whose height is specifically set to a value??

Comment: No I never specified a height in the outer-layout(s)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: No luck with the change :/

Comment: @webhoodlum what kind of design you need? and what your getting? Can you post that in snapshot?

Comment: @webhoodlum Change tab content fragment height as match_parent.

Comment: Where can I alter tab content fragment? Is that still my in XML?

Comment: @webhoodlum can you post that tab xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/title"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/body"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirm"
            android:text="@string/confirm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/btnEmail"
            android:alpha="1"   />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but no this didn't work :/